# "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_checkins" while permission is granted

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-checkins

I'm trying to make checkin with facebook sdk from iOS app and getting the following error.
Something wrong with the error description because user granted my app with the extended "publish_checkins" permission and it is mentioned in current session variable below:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1cd94430 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 200;
            message = "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_checkins";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1e05f9c0, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 592414770811425, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1e05fa80>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-08-09 00:21:49 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "publish_checkins",
    "user_about_me"
)>}
```

Please advice,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is turned out that "publish_checkins" permission is not supported now. I wasn't even able to add this permission at Facebook application configuration page (App Settings -> Permissions)

Now I post to timeline with place id and it works just fine (you have to ask for "publish_stream" instead of "publish_checkins" permission).

Thanks!

Comment: post to timeline with place id was working fine 2 days ago but now it returns an unknown error.Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Just checked and yes - my post to timeline was corrupted as well. The issue was that I posted placeid with location information. Now it is enough placeid and message.